# Find recent object changes in Firebird database

Tags: firebird

I am new to Firebird database. I was wondering does Firebird offer any query to get the information of tables updated after a specified date?

Just like what we can do in SQL Server using the following query.

```
select * 
from sys.objects 
where (type = 'U') 
  and modify_date > dateadd(d, -1, getdate())
```

I am looking for a similar query for a Firebird database.

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is not available in Firebird. Firebird does not keep track when a table or other object was changed.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt make special `TIMESTAMP` field and put there `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from `AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT` table `TRIGGER`. Then enumerate tables and see where last change is recent enough. However even this would not track DELETED rows. Basically you want to log all the changes and maybe even do database "replication", which in itself is rather complex area

Comment: After some research I found that firebird offers a logical table MON$Statements to query to get executed SQL_TEXTS.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt That only provides a snapshot of information at that point in time, it is not a historic record. If you want to keep track of it, you can try to use the trace facility.